# How to access maven pom properties in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

Pre-requisites:

- Multimodule Maven project
- Quarkus
- Java

I'm trying to access Maven build properties from java code: `project.atrifactId` and `project.parent.modules`:

Option 1 (didn't work): https://www.baeldung.com/java-accessing-maven-properties

Option 2 (didn't work): using via `@ConfigProperty`

Is there a way to access these properties from java code in quarkus?

Comment: Quarkus not provide a built in way of accessing these

Comment: I think the maven plugin "properties-maven-plugin" needs to used to generate the properties file. Please refer to https://dzone.com/articles/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-to-quarkus-migration and https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/maven-modules/maven-properties/pom.xml